# Only run php function once

Tags: php, mysql

I have this php function which checks a table in a database and checks to see if a user has a specific number in a field . This user could have a few rows where that filed has that number .

The problem with this is that it will run the if statement multiple times, triggering the resulting function to run multiple times. How can I stop this and just have the function say "okay found a match for al1 and running function , moving onto al2"

```
function countNewBadges() {
    require "connect.php"; 

    $count = mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT users.studentid, al1, al2, al3 FROM userbadges ub INNER JOIN users ON users.id = ub.user_id WHERE studentid = '".$_SESSION["studentid"]."'")  or die(mysqli_error($connection));

    while ($data = mysqli_fetch_array($count)) { 

    if ($data['al1'] == 1)
    { 
        unlockedBadges();
    }
    else if ($data['al2'] == 1)
    {
        echo "No New Badges";
    }
    else if ($data['al3'] == 1)
    {
        echo "No New Badges";
    }
}
}
```

Comment: `exit` or maybe `return` will stop execution.

Comment: use `return` to stop loop

Comment: @Kami: or `continue;` if he wants to move to the next entry.

Comment: @Drew your welcome. :)

Comment: @Script47  Actually return didnt work. It only works if i put return unlockedBadges();  What if I want to only have it return one for each

Comment: @Drew what do you mean by *return one for each*?

Comment: so its found something that matches al1 and returns the required thing for it , but there may be and al2 aswell which would be a different thing to return

Comment: Just a suggestion, edit your original question to clarify what you are asking, and give examples of what is your table and what the query returns, etc.. At the moment it's very unclear.

Comment: @Drew then add `return` to each `if statement`. Unless I'm missing something it seems fairly straightforward.

Comment: iv tried that , but what happens is that if both al1 and 2 have a match , the return for al2 will cancel out al1

Comment: Well yes, because `return` immediately ends execution, you may have to refine your `if statements`. Do you want all the `if statements` to run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I have the function say "okay found a match for al1 and running function, moving onto al2"

Just use a flag variable:

```
$flag = false;
while ($data = mysqli_fetch_array($count)) { 

    if ($data['al1'] == 1 && $flag === false)
    { 
        unlockedBadges();
        $flag = true;
    }
    else if ($data['al2'] == 1)
    {
        echo "No New Badges";
    }
    else if ($data['al3'] == 1)
    {
        echo "No New Badges";
    }
}
```

Comment: It should probably be combined (`if ( $data['al1'] == 1 && $flag === false)`) so it can "*move to a2*" on next iteration, if I understand correctly what the OP is asking (which I might not, since it's not very clear).

Comment: @rlanvin No probably about it. Otherwise this answer is nonsence

Comment: @rlanvin Actually, my code did the same. 2 sequential if-s are equivalent to and operator. Used your variant though.

Comment: @user4035 it's not equivalent at all when there is elseif/else. But apparently OP just wanted a `return` anyway, so this is irrelevant.

Comment: @rlanvin "it's not equivalent at all when there is elseif/else" - ahh, yes. It won't check ['al2'] and ['al3']. But with your improvements it will. "apparently OP just wanted a return" - no, I think he wanted to loop through all the values, that's why I didn't put as `return`.

Comment: @Drew "how would this work for all 3 ifs?" - what do you mean? The first if will be satisfied only once. It will call unlockedBadges() function only once.

Comment: for example , its found a match for al1 and runs the function and it wont run that again . It then moves to al2 and finds matches . How would i stop that running more than once

Comment: @user4035 Yep. OP said that "`return` worked" in the comments. Now indeed the comment has been edited, but the question is still very unclear. Good luck guessing!

Comment: @Drew "How would i stop that running more than once" add a flag for each condition you want to run once.

Answer (score 0):

While user4035's answer will stop multiple data entries to truly only run a function once you need to search and then act after (using as was said) a flag.

```
function countNewBadges() {
    require "connect.php"; 

    $count = mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT users.studentid, al1, al2, al3 FROM userbadges ub INNER JOIN users ON users.id = ub.user_id WHERE studentid = '".$_SESSION["studentid"]."'")  or die(mysqli_error($connection));

    $foundit=false;

    while ($data = mysqli_fetch_array($count)) { 

        if ($data['al1'] == 1)
        { 
            $foundit=true;
        }
        else if ($data['al2'] == 1)
        {
            echo "No New Badges";
        }
        else if ($data['al3'] == 1)
        {
            echo "No New Badges";
        }
    }
    if($foundit){
        unlockedBadges();
    }
}
```